# Can't query in admin node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have problem where with very similar code that I run on JavaScript doesn't work on node.js:

```
 exports.findDate = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log("helo: " + req.query.text); // this works

    var ref = admin.database().ref("messages/events");
    const query = ref.orderByChild("start").equalTo(req.query.text);
    query.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val().title);
        res.status(200).send('ok1' + snapshot.toJSON().title);
    });
    res.status(200).send('ok'); //this print in browser
});
```

Strangely, only things outside the query work. What can cause it?

**updated code:**

```
exports.getEvents = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

        admin.database().ref('events').orderByValue().once('value', function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.val().title);
            res.status(200).send('ok1');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error('Error while reading data', error);
            res.status(403).send('Error');
        });
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
query.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val().title);
    res.status(200).send('ok1' + snapshot.toJSON().title);
});
```

Comment: still receiving `ok` instead of `ok1`

Answer (score 0):

You can't send back two statuses. Since the `.once` is asynchronous, the status of 'ok' is returned before that work is done. If you check the Firebase console, you'll probably have some errors indicating you're trying to send more than one response. I tried out your code as is and got an error like this:
[image]

You don't need to send the second status response. If you are looking to include a catch block, you can do so like this:

```
query.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val().title);
    res.status(200).send('ok1');
}).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error while reading data', error);
    res.status(403).send('Error');
});
```

Comment: Seems like it's working now - got to do more tests :) One more question: are Cloud Functions always that slow? Doing operations from client is sooo much faster than doing it via Cloud.

Comment: Looks like some more info may be needed. Add your logs from the Firebase console to your question and update your code from your question to show what it looks like now.

Comment: Just updated. I get only `Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'`

Comment: All the logs. So for instance, what does it show for the value of `snapshot.val().title`? You could include a screenshot of the logs.

Comment: That's all I got. No console log, no error - looks like it stops on query and do nothing further. Updated question with screenshot.

Comment: Just for the record: security rules are in place

Comment: And this is what browser prints: `Error: could not handle the request`

Comment: I just tested your code and it worked for me. I was able to get a response back, log the data, and see the logs in the console. Which versions of firebase-functions and firebase-admin are you using?

Comment: I started development 2 weeks ago so I think I have the recent ones.Here is the function in question: https://us-central1-terminarz-28eeb.cloudfunctions.net/getEvents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152970/discussion-between-jen-person-and-jean-darme).